# Computing Conditional Variance

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have been tasked with trying to solve a conditional variance. I have red and black pens with respective exponential probability parameters 2 and 4. I have 70% red pens and 30% black pens. What is the variance of the lifespan?

This is what I have so far: Let Y which batch it is from
$$Var(X)=V(X)=E(V(X|Y))+V(E(X|Y))$$
I broke this down and solved:
$$E(V(X|Y))=V(X|Y=red)*P(red)+V(X|Y=black)*P(black)=\frac{1}{2^2}*.7+\frac{1}{4^2}*.3=.19375$$
$$V(E(X|Y))= E([E(X|Y)]^2)-[E(E(X|Y))]^2$$
However, $E(E(X|Y))=E(X)$, which I have already solved. How does one find the $E([E(X|Y)]^2)$ part now. The E(X) is below
$$E(X)=E(E(X|Y))=E(X|Y=red)*P(red)+E(X|Y=black)*P(black)$$
Then each respective $E(X|Y=n)=\int_0^{\inf} xf_x$ such that $f_x$ is the respective exponential probabilities with parameters. Therefore $E(X)=.425$.

Comment: Busy with work right now but commenting because it looks interesting. I'll take a look later :)

Comment: Unless this is some notational shorthand I'm not familiar with, you have some parentheses-balancing issues that's making it difficult for me to parse your equations.  Can you clarify?  (Either explaining the unbalanced parentheses notation, or fixing it?)

Comment: Also, to clarify what you're trying to determine: The red pens have a lifetime that is exponentially distributed with rate $2$ (equivalently, with mean lifetime $1/2$), and black pens with rate $4$ (equivalently, with mean lifetime $1/4$), is that right?  And you want to find the variance of the lifetime of a single pen drawn from a collection of pens that is $70$ percent red and $30$ percent black, is that correct?

Comment: yes. I will fix the above part. Sorry

Comment: Any new thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find $E([E(X|Y)]^2)$:

Firstly, $E(X|Y)$, which is a function of $Y$ is given by:

$$E(X|Y) =
\begin{cases}
1/2,  & \text{if $Y$ is red} \\
1/4, & \text{if $Y$ is black}
\end{cases}$$

And so,

$$(E(X|Y))^2 =
\begin{cases}
(1/2)^2,  & \text{if $Y$ is red} \\
(1/4)^2, & \text{if $Y$ is black}
\end{cases}$$

Taking expectation of this, we have

\begin{eqnarray*}
E([E(X|Y)]^2) &=& (1/2)^2 P(Y=\text{red}) + (1/4)^2 P(Y=\text{black}) \\
&=& \dfrac{1}{4}0.7 + \dfrac{1}{16}0.3 \\
&=& 0.19375.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: thank you. I am also assuming there is no errors in the above work? Primarily with the numbers?

Comment: @JackArmstrong Hi Jack. Your work/numbers look correct to me.